# Customer Lifetime Value based on RFM (Mixing logistic and linear regression)

Tags: predictive-models, references, marketing

I'm trying to build a simple model to compute Customer Lifetime Value (CLV) based on Recency, Frequency and Monetary (R,F,M). Browsing the web, I've found this question [RFM & customer lifetime value modeling in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20463/rfm-customer-lifetime-value-modeling-in-r) and after having looked at the answer given, some doubts have arisen:

1. One of the approaches consists of the following:

   > *Another popular approach is to build a slightly more complex model for predicting monetary value based on two sub-models: one for probability of response (e.g. using logistic regression as a function of RFM), and the other for revenue conditional on response (again, it could be as simple as a linear model of RFM). Expected monetary value is the product of the two predictions.*

I already had my logistic regression output, but I don't know how to mix the response given by it (probability of response) in order to run, for instance, a linear regression for revenue. As you might realize, in the answer quoted above, it's said that it's done conditionally on response, but how can be this carried out? How can I mix those models?

2. Is it OK if I regress revenue (monetary) on the probability *P* given by logistic regression? I'm afraid this variable is somehow included since I obtained it by running a model with *R, F* and *M* as predictor variables.
3. Would you please provide me with some online resources (papers) to get more of this topic?

Comment: Check out the BTYD R package, which has some models for calculating CLV based on RFM statistics. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/index.html

Comment: Yeah, I already checked that. Great approach by Fader et al. However, I'm right now interested in regression-type models like the one described above to tackle this task.